# Java Sandboxed Environment In Contrast to C

Tags: java, c, sandbox

> Java is designed to run in a “Sandboxed” environment in contrast to C which is not constrained.  Discuss the implications of this from a security point of view.

I have done a bit of research in regards to the concept. What I found was if it's sandboxed where Java runs on, it goes through a more controlled door to retrieve information from different parts of memory. However, in C, it doesn't where it is uncontrolled.

Can someone please explain if there is anything else that I can add?

### Edit:

This is what I have added:

Java programming language is an object-oriented language specifically designed to have as few implementation dependencies as possible. Java is write once deploy many times model. It is superficially like C/C++/C# but have different underlying object model. There are many versions of Java such as Java Standard Edition (Java SE), Java Mobile Edition (Java ME), Java Enterprise Edition (Java EE) etc.

The applications written in java are compiled to Java byte code which is an intermediate language independent of any platform. Thus, compiler can work multi platform.

The Virtual Machine model of compilation and execution works by running the compiled code (Java byte code) on Java Virtual Machine (JVM). Java Virtual Machine interprets java byte code and provides an environment in which Java byte code can be executed. The use of the same byte code for all JVMs on all platforms allow Java to be described as a “write once, run anywhere”.

This is better model than the compiler that generates native code due to following reasons:

1. Mobile devices come in various shape and sizes and with varying processor speed and architecture. Therefore, the virtual machine model of compilation and execution allows all java apps to run on various different mobile platforms once JVM is implemented on a device.
2. The virtual machine mode of compilation provide a platform-independent programming environment that abstracts away details of the underlying hardware or operating system, and allows a program to execute in the same way on any platform.
3. Performance comparable to compiled programming languages is achieved by the use of just-in-time compilation (a method to improve the runtime performance of computer program).
4. Compilation from byte code to machine code is much faster than compiling from source.
5. The deployed byte code is portable, unlike native code.
6. Since the runtime has control over the compilation, like interpreted byte code, it can run in a secure sandbox. Compilers from byte code to machine code are easier to write, because the portable byte code compiler has already done much of the work.

Comment: That's a pretty short answer to the question; it'd be best to at least talk about the Security Manager, the use of _stack_ information for determining security controls in Java, and why something similar in C would be difficult to do well.

Comment: Ok Thanks, Thats why I have added to this Stack Overflow.. So I am able to get more information and more points to add to the answer.

Comment: If it's homework, tag it homework.  Giving you benefit of the doubt...

Comment: I have now.. Sorry, New to this

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix languages and virtualisation.

Google's Native Client (NaCL) is a sandboxed environment for C/C++ (and everything else) programs, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 'quick sampling' of the most common security challenges for sand-boxed code, off the top of my head.

In a sand-boxed app. restrictions will be added in the areas of:

- Printing.
- Cross-domain resource access.
- Copy/Paste.
- Import/export of resources from/to the local file system.
- Applet calling `System.exit(n)`.
- Call applet methods from JavaScript..
- Warnings attached to free floating elements.  Which can even apply to tool-tips of apps. using 3rd party PLAFs.
- Access to a variety of properties (e.g. `user.*`, any number of `java.*` props)
- Load and use natives (that should be obvious).
- Start processes.
- Redirect output or error streams.
- Record sound or video.
- Access to the `Robot`.
- ..

If this question is about 'security', you have a lot of research to do.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Java is inherently "sandboxable", whereas C++ et al are not.  In Java there is no way to get outside of an object -- you can't freely cast an object pointer to `char*`, for instance, and you can't address beyond the end of an array.

Access to system facilities is limited by in several ways (some of which I forget just now).  But basically one can run a Java program that loads secure class loaders and the like, and then any application that is loaded in that environment is "corralled" and cannot do anything that you don't wish to let it do.

(In fact, the "classic" JVM on IBM iSeries made use of these features to prevent even the "main" Java program from running amok.  Java code ran in the same address space as the OS, but still the OS was protected by Java's inherent security.)

In C++ et al, in order to accomplish the same thing, you either have to make use of storage protection hardware or else have a compiler that compiles in checks of every access.